# C programming find min,max and sum without using recursion and arrays

Tags: c, sum, max, min

I am trying to write a program that get bunch of numbers, n >= 5
The program asks from the user to enter n non-negative numbers and calculate min,max and the sum of the numbers.
In case the user enter negative numbers, the function asks to enter a positive number.
I have a problem with the first negative number, any clue what's wrong with the following code?

```
void main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x >= 5)
    {
        int max = 0, min, num1;
        printf("Enter numbers: \n");
        scanf("%d", &num1); //here was the error
        min = num1;
        int sum = num1;
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &num1); 
            while (num1 < 0)
            {
                {
                    printf("Enter again number: /n");
                    scanf("%d", &num1);
                }
            }
            if (num1 > max)
                max = num1;
            else if (num1 < min)
                min = num1;
            sum += num1;
        }
        printf("The max number is %d, and the min is %d, and the sum is %d", max, min, sum);
    }
    else
        printf("invalid number!");
}

output:

Enter number:
8
Enter numbers:
-8
7
6
9
10
6
7
6
The max number is 10, and the min is -8, and the sum is 43
```

Comment: You are not maintaining `min` etc in the case where the number entered was `>= 0`. Move that stuff down out of the code block that re-inputs `num1`.

Comment: Two instances where `scanf("%d", num1);` should be `scanf("%d", &num1);` Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: ...also the innermost braces don't form a code block that actually needs them.

Answer (score 0):

check if `min<0` assign new entered value of `num1` to it.

```
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            if (min < 0)
                min = num1;
            while (num1 < 0){
            //rest of the code}
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with the first negative number, any clue what's wrong with the following code?

Do not read first number with special code, which lacks a negative test.  Simplify and read just like other numbers.

Simply start `min,max` with extremes.

```
#include <limits.h>

    ...
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // start at 0
        int num1;
        scanf("%d", &num1); 
        while (num1 < 0) {
            printf("Enter again number: /n");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
        }
        if (num1 > max)
            max = num1;
        // else if (num1 < min)
        if (num1 < min)
            min = num1;
        sum += num1;
    }
    printf("The max number is %d, and the min is %d, and the sum is %d", 
        max, min, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put while after taking the input from the user to prevent any negative number also inside while there isn't need to put double cure prates

`````````````
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if (x >= 5)
    {
        int max = 0, min, num1,sum;

        printf("Enter numbers:\n");



        sum = 0;
        min = num1;

        for (int i = 1; i<=x; i++)
        {   
            scanf("%d",&num1); 

             while(num1<0)
        {
            printf("Enter again number: \n ");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
        }


            if (num1 > max)
               { max = num1;}
            if (num1<min)
               { min = num1;}

          sum += num1;
        }
        printf("The max number is %d, and the min is %d, and the sum is %d", max, min, sum);
    }
    else
        printf("invalid number!");


 return 0;
}
````````````
`````````````